# let and const keyword giving error in typescript after compilation. Where as var works fine

Tags: typescript, compilation, constants, var, let

I am very new to typescript i am trying to work out watcing a tutorial. I am face this issue when i use const and let. After compilation ts file shows some error mark. But getting output when using node filename.js. Same code when using var does not show any issue. Can u help me solve this? I have attached the screenshot and small line of code below [While using const](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiODy.png),  [While using var](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99cTr.png)[image: error], `[let message:string = 'Hello Word'; console.log(message);][4]`

Comment: You need to include the source code as formatted text here in your question and not via images or source hosted on third party systems. Those systems can go offline, the content can be removed, or even changed, affecting the value of this question to those looking for an answer in the future.

Comment: You should also include the exact text of the error message in the body of your question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `tsconfig.json` is probably missing `exclude` and `include`. Without these, VSCode treats all files in your current workspace as if they were in one namespace. Because your TypeScript source file has a variable named `message`, and your compiled JavaScript file also has a variable named `message`, VSCode believes that these definitions will "clash".

You should explicitly specify which files to include and exclude in your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": { ... },
    "include": ["**/*.ts"], // or maybe some other paths
    "exclude": ["**/*.js"], // don't include javascript files
}
```

You can change these later to your needs; the values I have provided here include all TypeScript files and excludes all JavaScript files.

As for why only `var` works, it's because `var` allows you to "redeclare" or shadow variables without errors:

```
var myVariable = "hi!";
var myVariable = 42; //
```